# Android studio 2.1.3 - Android app building failed due to ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to run my android app for the first time but i got this error message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> Implementing class

I found an answer saying it could be a problem with conflicting dependencies but i'm not quite sure how to resolve that.

Comment: delete the `.gradle` folder in your project then `clean` the project and `Rebuild` it.

Comment: I tried that but im still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

- Close `Android Studio`
- Go to your app's directory,
- Delete both `build` folders (I mean: `build` and `app/build`)
- Unhide hidden files to see `.gradle` folder (it's `Gradle` config dir)
- Remove `.gradle` folder
- Open `Android Studio`. Deleted files would be recreated on AS run

Hope it will help